# Proving that $L = \{0^k \mid \text{$k$ is composite}\}$ is not regular by pumping lemma

Tags: formal-languages

> Suppose $L = \{0^k \mid \text{$k$ is composite}\}$. Prove that this language is not regular.

What bugs me in this lemma is that when I choose a string in $L$ and try to consider all cases of dividing it into three parts so that in each case it violates lemma, I always find one case that does not violate it. A bit of help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

---

**My attempt:**

1. Suppose that $L$ is regular.
2. Choosing string $x = 0^{2k}$ where $k$ is prime ($2k$ pumping constant)
3. We can divide $x$ into three parts $u, v, w$ such that:
   $$|uv| \le 2k \qquad |v| > 0\qquad uv^iw \in L \text{ for $i \ge 0$}$$
4. If $u$ and $w$ are empty, all conditions are met.

It is the same when I change $2$ for any other number. Maybe I'm choosing wrong.

Comment: Is it a requirement that you use the pumping lemma? The [Myhill-Nerode therorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem) shows this immediately because the distribution of composite numbers never repeats. (More precisely, the function $k\mapsto \{ n \mid k+n\text{ is composite}\}$ not only has an infinite image, but _is injective_).

Comment: yes, it is a requirement

Comment: i'll show by editing question, please, wait

Comment: Um, hold on, the pumping lemma actually _doesn't_ show directly that language is non-regular. If you absolutely must pump, try applying the pumping lemma to the _complement_ of $L$.

Comment: why so? i can't quite undestand your point

Comment: The complement of a regular language is regular (easily demonstrated by inverting which states are accepting), so if the complement is not regular then neither is the original language. And no infinite arithmetic sequence of integers contains only primes.

Comment: i'm having the same problem in choosing a string for a language where k must be prime, can you help in that case?

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev: please don't repost. Improve the question or offer a bounty if you need more answers.

Comment: i don't have so many rep to offer bounty

Comment: I gave you a complete answer for the version in which $k$ must be prime, and by taking complements that gives you an answer for the original problem as well. You won’t be able to use the pumping lemma directly on the original $L$.

Comment: "You won’t be able to use the pumping lemma directly on the original $L$." Well, you *can*, it's just arguably simpler to solve the problem for $L'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t assume that the pumping constant is even. If you want to start with a word of the form $0^{2k}$ for some $k$, that’s fine, but you can’t take $2k$ to be the pumping constant $p$; you can only assume that $2k\ge p$. But trying to use the pumping lemma directly to prove that $L$ is not regular is going to be a bit difficult. I would use the fact that the regular languages are closed under complementation, so if $L$ is regular, so is

$$L'=\{0^n:n\text{ is prime}\}\;.$$

Now apply the pumping lemma to $L'$. I’ve done it in the spoiler-protected text below, but I think that you can probably do it yourself without the help.

> Let $p$ be the pumping length, and start with $x=0^n$ for some prime $n\ge p$. Decompose $x$ in the usual way as $uvw$, so that $|uv|\le p$, $|v|>0$, and $uv^kw\in L$ for $k\ge 0$. Let $a=|uw|$ and $m=|v|>0$; then for each $k\ge 0$ you have $|uv^kw|=a+km$. In other words, the lengths of the words $uv^kw$ form an arithmetic sequence with first term $a$ and constant difference $m$. You should have no trouble showing that this sequence must contain a composite number.

Comment: thanks, that was comprehensible

Comment: @Kudayar: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Albeit mathematical overkill, here is one way to use the pumping lemma directly to prove the result.

Suppose $L$ is regular; then, let the pumping length be $n \geq 1$. By the infinitude of primes, let $p$ be an odd prime greater than $n$. Consider the string $0^{p^2} \in L$. Since $|0^{p^2}| = p^2 > p > n$, by the pumping lemma, there exists a decomposition $0^{p^2} = uvw$ where $|uv| \leq n$, $|v| > 0$, and $uv^kw \in L$ for all $k \geq 0$.

Note the inequality $0 < |v| \leq |uv| \leq n < p$; in particular, $0 < |v| < p$, which implies $\gcd(|v|, p) = 1$ via the primality of $p$. This further implies that $\gcd(|v|,p^2) = \gcd(|v|, p^2 - |v|) = 1$.

Now note that $uv^kw = 0^{p^2 + (k - 1)|v|}$, so that the lengths of the strings generated by pumping is precisely an arithmetic progression with $p^2 - |v|$ as the initial term, and $|v|$ as the common difference. As we have shown that $\gcd(p^2 - |v|, |v|) = 1$, Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions states that this arithmetic progression contains infinitely many primes; thus, there exists $k' \geq 0$ such that $p^2 - |v| + k'|v| = p^2 + (k' - 1)|v|$ is prime. As $0^{p^2 + (k' - 1)|v|} = uv^{k'}w \in L$, we have a contradiction.