# Proving that language is not regular by pumping lemma

Tags: formal-languages

> Suppose $L = \{0^k \mid \text{$k$ is composite}\}$. Prove that this language is not regular.

What bugs me in this lemma is that when I choose a string in $L$ and try to consider all cases of dividing it into three parts so that in each case it violates lemma, I always find one case that does not violate it. A bit of help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

---

**My attempt:**

1. Suppose that $L$ is regular.
2. Choosing string $x = 0^{2k}$ where $k$ is prime ($2k$ pumping constant)
3. We can divide $x$ into three parts $u, v, w$ such that:
   $$|uv| \le 2k \qquad |v| > 0\qquad uv^iw \in L \text{ for $i \ge 0$}$$
4. If $u$ and $w$ are empty, all conditions are met.

It is the same when I change $2$ for any other number. Maybe I'm choosing wrong.

Comment: Note: It is rude and abusive to delete [your earlier question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/355900/proving-that-language-is-not-regular-by-pumping-lemma) and repost it again without the comments it had already gathered.