# context free language prove or disprove

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

I have to prove or disprove that for every language $L$ which has the properties:

1. for every non-prime length there is at least one word in L.
2. for every prime length none of the words are in L.

is not a context-free language.

I think it is true and there is no context-free language which has the two properties above but I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Try using the [pumping lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages) for context-free languages, and [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) on the infinity of primes in certain arithmetic progressions to prove that the two conditions are inconsistent with $\ L$'s being context-free.

You should be able to show that under the first given condition, if $\ L\ $ were context-free, there would have to exist a word $\ uvwxy \ $, pumpable to  $\ uv^nwx^ny\ $ for any positive integer $\ n\ $, in which $\ \vert uvwxy\,\vert\ $ (and hence also $\ \vert uwy\,\vert\ $) is relatively prime to $\ \vert vx\,\vert\ $.  It would then follow from Dirichlet's theorem that $\ L\ $ must contain a word of prime length.

Answer (score 1):

Both assertions are wrong. Let $A$ be a nonempty alphabet.

Take $L = A^*$, which is of course context-free. For each length $n$ (non-prime or not), there is a word of length $n$ in $L$. Thus (1) is satisfied.

Now take $L = \emptyset$, which is also context-free. Then for each length $n$ (prime or not), there is no word of length $n$ in $L$. Thus (2) is satisfied.

**EDIT**. A language satisfying (1) and (2) simultaneously cannot be context-free. Indeed, let $f:  A^* \to a^*$ be the monoid homomorphism defined by $f(u) = a^{|u|}$ and let $K = f(L)$. By condition (1) and (2), one gets 
$$K = \{a^p \mid \text{$p$ is not prime} \}$$

If $L$ was context-free, then $K$ would be context-free, since context-free languages are closed under homomorphisms. Moreover, a context-free language on a one-letter alphabet is regular (this is a special case of [Parikh's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parikh%27s_theorem)). You can now conclude by using the pumping lemma (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1637151) for more details).

Comment: I took the qestion to be whether a language that has *both* properties can be context-free.  I don't believe it can, for the reasons suggested in my answer.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Thank you for your remark. I edited my answer to treat this case as well.

Comment: Under the two conditions  shouldn't $\ K\ $ be $\ \{ a^c\,\vert\, c \ge 0,\ \mbox{ not prime }\,\}\ $.  Although the statements of the conditions aren't entirely clear, I read the first as saying that $\ L\ $ contains a word of every non-prime length, and the second as saying that it contains  no words of any prime length.  I think your proof still works, but I think it needs to be shown that you can choose a pumpable word that will pump out one of prime length, which doesn't seem to me to be an entirely trivial observation.

Comment: Thanks again. You are perfectly right, it is "not prime". For the second part of you comment, isn't it what is done in the linked answer?

Comment: Yes, apologies  for not looking carefully enough at the linked example.  While it doesn't do what I suggested, the method it does use is an easier way of arriving at the end result, thus showing that what I suggested was not necessary.